# how to convert curl -F command with retrofit2

Tags: java, retrofit2

I want use retrofit2 with Spring.
But I don't know how to convert that.

curl command below

```
curl --location --request POST 'api-url' \
--header 'x-chain-id: PORT' \
--header 'Authorization: API-KEY' \
--form 'file=@"/img-path"'
```

and I will make image file from image url and make MultipartBody.part like below

```
            URL url = new URL("url");

            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(url);
            tempFile = new File("path");

            ImageIO.write(image, "png", tempFile);

            MultipartBody.Part filePart = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", tempFile.getName(), RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), tempFile));
            RequestBody fbody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"),
                    tempFile);
```

and call interface method

```
    @Multipart
@POST("v1/metadata/asset")
Call<Asset> getAsset(@Header("Authorization") String authentication, @Header("x-chain-id") String chainId,
        @Part("file\"; filename=\"pp.png\" ") RequestBody file);
```

Where is wrong?